# Unable to connect Samsung S10 to charles proxy

Tags: charles-proxy

With device manual proxy to my Charles IP address, not seeing any traffic or prompt to allow traffic in Charles Proxy. S10 device appears to load all traffic when navigating to various URLs.

Even charlesproxy.com/ssl loads website but doesn't initiate a certificate to download.

All other android devices tested on same setup works fine. Issue seems specific to Samsung S10

Comment: any update on this question?

Answer (score 0):

So what seemed to have worked for me just now, with my mac (I assume it would be something similar for Windows) I just opened a regular browser, went to chls.pro/ssl and download the certificate file.

From there I sent it to my S10+ and opened it, which then installed it properly.

Answer (score 0):

If you're trying to hook up to Android devices then beware that Google introduced security measures to not allow proxy monitoring in I believe Android 6 or 7.  If the other devices you had worked fine on Android then it's probably because you were using an earlier version of Android, or, you had a debug build that allowed for proxy monitoring.  I know there's a SO post somewhere that talks about this "pinning" and I know our company does this as well with debug apk's.  If neither of those solutions work then it's probably a matter of getting the Charles certificate installed correctly on that phone but without more information it is hard to diagnose.  Hope this helps you

Comment: Yes I have been using a debug build for testing with Charles, so the additional security measures you mention haven't effected my use. The OS doesn't seem to be the factor here. I have tried the same the same build on an S9 - 9.0 and had no problem. S10 - 9.0 device is the one that seems to not take the charles certificate.